# Can I host a web app with a server that is using Socket.io in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, socket.io

I want to use Firebase for hosting and database only and I'm thinking of using socket.io for syncing data between users in real-time.

I'm building a web app like Google Docs where multiple users can edit a file at the same time (Collaborative Editing).

I know I can sync data in real-time using Firebase Realtime Database but I don't want to because it has limits on reads/writes that could cost me money.

Comment: Firebase has Cloud Function but they do not run forever, the instances shutdown eventually. Checkout [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets) instead. Cloud Functions Gen 2 use Cloud Run but I haven't tried using Socket IO with them yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.